# In Arcadedb how do I get a list of vertex types that are subtypes to a supertype?

Tags: sql, graph-databases, arcadedb

I need to get a list of vertex types from the database that are subtypes to a supertype.

I.e. If I have a vertex structure that goes:

View -> Type1 -> Custom_Type_1

View -> Type1 -> Custom_Type_2

View -> Type2 -> Custom_Type_3

I want to be able to query....

"Get all type names that are subtypes to 'Type1'." So that it returns Custom_Type_1 and Custom_Type_2.

Note it is the type names I want, not the actual vertices of that type.  I assume there must be a database metadata somewhere that could be queried but I can't find anything in the documentation to do this.

Am learning as ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the schema and ask for the types with parent type equals to Type1:

```sql
select name from schema:types where 'Type1' IN parentTypes
```

[image]

Comment: Legend. Thanks Luca.  And I've just taken a look at your profile.  Brilliant system you've created here.

Comment: Thanks, Rob! I hope to see you around ArcadeDB community.